# function in function

Tags: python

how can I make the func. show all the bad values and not just one?

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
        for i in person_results:
                if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2]:
                    return i[0]

test_results = [["White blood cells",8.5,2,7],
                ["Neutrophils",5.3,2.5,5],
                ["Red blood cells", 12.4, 9,15]]

a = get_bad_results(test_results)
print a
```

show `White blood cells`

instead of

```
White blood cells, Neutrophils
```

Comment: Please do not use the `homework` tag, it's being removed from SO.

Comment: And `get_bad_results` does not have a `return` statement, so its result will *always* be `None`. `count_healthy` doesn't return anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you expect several results per call, it is the best to use a generator function:

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
    for i in person_results:
        if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2]:
            yield i[0]
```

or a generator expression:

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
    return (i[0] for i in person_results if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2])
```

so that

```
test_results = [["White blood cells",8.5,2,7],
                ["Neutrophils",5.3,2.5,5],
                ["Red blood cells", 12.4, 9,15]]

for i in get_bad_results(test_results):
    print i
print list(get_bad_results(test_results))
print ", ".join(get_bad_results(test_results))
```

gives the output

```
White blood cells
Neutrophils
['White blood cells', 'Neutrophils']
White blood cells, Neutrophils
```

For the other function, do

```
def count_healthy(all_results):
    counter = 0
    for i in all_results:
        if len(list(get_bad_results(i))) == 0:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

or just

```
def count_healthy(all_results):
    return sum(1 for i in all_results if len(list(get_bad_results(i))) == 0)
```

---

Edit:

For many `get_bad_results()`, turning it into a list could be memory-intensive.

So instead of `len(list(get_bad_results(i))) == 0` you could use

```
def has_results(it):
    """Returns True if the iterator it yields any items."""
    return next((True for _ in it), False)
```

and then

```
def count_healthy(all_results):
    return sum(1 for i in all_results if not has_results(get_bad_results(i)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `count_healthy()` function doesn't `return` a value, so `b` is `None`. Since the function does a print, which is then followed by the `print b`, that explains the output of a `None` after the output from the function.

Basically, a function that is supposed to do a count probably shouldn't *also* be printing the result, but should instead `return` it so the caller can decide the result should be printed or handled differently.

Comment: tnx!
i changed it and now everything works fine except when in the first func there are more that 1 value that is out of range, its print always only one valuse.

'code'def get_bad_results(person_results):
        for i in person_results:
                if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2]:
                    return i[0]
                            
test_results = [["White blood cells",8.5,2,7],
                ["Neutrophils",5.3,2.5,5],
                ["Red blood cells", 12.4, 9,15]]

a = get_bad_results(test_results)
print a
'code'

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `None`.

Try adding a `return` statement and return the value that you want to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print result of functions

```
a = get_bad_results(test_results)
print a

b =count_healthy(all_results)
print b
```

By default functions return None

Comment: how can i fix it to print only the name of the test?

Comment: You can just call it without print

Comment: but i need to print the answer

Comment: You mean 'counter' variable? Then write 'return counter'.

Comment: now it print :
"White blood cells
White blood cells
White blood cells
Neutrophils
3"

Comment: It makes sense to me that it would print that. After all, that's what `get_bad_results` does: it prints the bad results. If you don't want `get_bad_results` to print bad results, then remove the `print` statement inside its definition. (Hint: maybe it should _return_ a list of bad results, rather than print each bad result as it comes across it)

Answer (score 0):

ok I fixed it but now

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
        for i in person_results:
                if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2]:
                    return i[0]

test_results = [["White blood cells",8.5,2,7],
                ["Neutrophils",5.3,2.5,5],
                ["Red blood cells", 12.4, 9,15]]

a = get_bad_results(test_results)
print a
```

show `White blood cells`

instead of `White blood cells, Neutrophils`

Comment: Don't ask how to proceed in an answer. Instead, edit your question accordingly.