# function output

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308553/function-in-function)

how can I make the func. show all the bad values and not just one?

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
        for i in person_results:
                if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2]:
                    return i[0]

test_results = [["White blood cells",8.5,2,7],
                ["Neutrophils",5.3,2.5,5],
                ["Red blood cells", 12.4, 9,15]]

a = get_bad_results(test_results)
print a
```

show `White blood cells`

instead of

```
White blood cells, Neutrophils
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13308553/989121. Please do not double post. Keep this place clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function will return the first occurrence that fits the statement. To return all, you could save them away in a list and when the loop is done, return the list.

```
for i in person_results:
    bads = []
    if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2]:
        bads.append(i[0])
return bads
```

Comment: This isn't a great way of doing it. For one, constructing a list is not very memory efficient, compared to a generator, and also, if one was to construct a list, a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) would be the much better way of doing it here.

Comment: @Lattyware: I agree, but I chose the simplest approach to the problem, but it's not the most effective way. In my opinion, your answer is the best for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `yield` keyword, which produces a generator:

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
        for i in person_results:
                if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2]:
                    yield i[0]
```

You can then iterate over the results of the function (for example, calling `list()` to create a list). A generator is preferable to producing the list directly as it means the values are generated lazily, which is more memory-efficient in a lot of cases.

As a side note, indexing `i` is a little ugly, in this case, unpacking the values would make your code far more readable:

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
        for name, age, height, weight in person_results:
                if age > weight or age < height:
                    yield name
```

(Naturally, I have made up names here as I don't know the context).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a generator, you can append the bad elements to a list and then return it:

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
    bad_results = []
    for i in person_results:
        if i[1] > i[3] or i[1] < i[2]:
            bad_results.append(i[0])
    return bad_results
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
    return [i[0] for i in person_results if i[1] > i[3] or i[1] < i[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just print from your function that already is doing the compare? Then you don't need anything additional to track

```
def get_bad_results(person_results):
        for i in person_results:
                if i[1]>i[3] or i[1]<i[2]:
                    print i[0]
```